# ms-access: DB engine cannot find input table or query

Tags: sql, ms-access

here's the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Occurrence Number], [Occurrence Date], [1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)], [Cup Type], NULL as [2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)], [2 0 Area], NULL as [3 0 Postanalytical ( After Testing)],NULL as  [4 0 Other], [Practice Code], [Specimen ID #] FROM [Lab Occurrence Form] 
WHERE NOT ([1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] IS NULL)
  UNION
  SELECT [Occurrence Number],  [Occurrence Date],NULL, [Cup Type],[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)],  [2 0 Area], NULL,NULL, [Practice Code], [Specimen ID #] FROM  [Lab Occurrence Form]  WHERE NOT ([2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)] IS NULL)
  UNION
  SELECT  [Occurrence Number],  [Occurrence Date],NULL, [Cup Type],NULL,  [2 0 Area], [3 0 Postanalytical ( After Testing)],NULL, [Practice Code], [Specimen ID #] FROM  [Lab Occurrence Form]  WHERE NOT ([3 0 Postanalytical ( After Testing)] IS NULL)
 UNION
  SELECT  [Occurrence Number],  [Occurrence Date],NULL, [Cup Type],NULL, [2 0 Area], NULL,  [4 0 Other] FROM  [Lab Occurrence Form], [Practice Code], [Specimen ID #]  WHERE NOT ([4 0 Other] IS NULL)
)  AS mySubQuery
ORDER BY mySubQuery.[Occurrence Number];
```

for some reason it doesnt like [Practice Code]. it's definitely a column in the table so i dont understand the problem.

the error is

the microsoft office access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Practice Code'........

Comment: You're really making life difficult for yourself with such awful names for your tables and fields. Lose all the spaces and special characters (no "#" for instance) and life will be a lot easier.

Comment: While the Access QBE doesn't make it easy to edit UNION queries, you should definitely paste the individual statements into the QBE and see if they each run individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error says it all. It is not a table. In your question, you state that it is a column in a table.
You have `[Lab Occurrence Form], [Practice Code], [Specimen ID #]` right after a from, so it assumes all those listed there are tables.

Answer (score 2):

The last SQL SELECT in the UNION has a messed up FROM clause:

```
  SELECT [Occurrence Number],  [Occurrence Date],NULL, [Cup Type],NULL, [2 0 Area], NULL,  [4 0 Other] 
  FROM  [Lab Occurrence Form], [Practice Code], [Specimen ID #]  
  WHERE NOT ([4 0 Other] IS NULL)
```

You seem to have put two fields in the FROM clause, [Practice Code] and [Specimen ID #].